How to extend ext4/xfs size of / partition without lvm with additional hdd/ssd in server
How to extend ext4/xfs size of / partition without lvm with additional hdd/ssd in server.
I have tried with dmsetup but unable to do so.

You can't if you don't have LVM or if you never set up RAID.  The best you can do is create a second partition on that extra disk, and then mount it somewhere and write to data on that path.  Otherwise, you have to back up your data, RAID or LVM the drives, and then reload your data back on.
